# iptables ipset misconfiguration?

Tags: networking, iptables, ipset

I'm looking for a solid method to block unwanted TCP/IP traffic.

On my linux machine iptables and ipset seem to offer a nice way to do so.

Until now I've done this:

```
ipset create ipsok hash:net maxelem (result of wc -l for my cidr list in a file)
ipset add <network address>
```

And made sure this is the only ipset using:

```
service ipset status
```

This shows only ipset ipsok with the right number of entries. I've also made sure the ipset is used after a reboot. Then I add the ipset to the iptables rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set ipsok src -j ACCEPT
```

To test if this works I let TOR provide me with an ip address and check this with:

```
ipset test ipsok <tor ip address>
```

This tells me the address is **NOT** in the ipsok set.

When I direct the tor browser to my machine the connection is made. Is this correct? I thought the connection would fail because the ip address is not found in the ipset.

What do I need to do to make iptables (and ipset) block traffic **NOT** coming from any network address in ipset ipsok?

Comment: Do you have a rule after the set accept that will drop or reject the traffic that doesn't match?

Comment: Your displayed rules are not useful to us without more context - we would need the output of `iptables-save` to answer your question with something else than a reasonable guess.

Answer (score 0):

Iptables' default policy is `ACCEPT`. So by adding IPs to your list, you're only ACCEPTing them twice.

Your `iptables -L` should show as much - that is, the only rules will be ACCEPT rules.

Change the default to DROP, then add your items to ACCEPT.

Try this before your match set rule:
`iptables -P INPUT DROP`

Be careful - don't do this remotely or you're likely to lock yourself out.